# Extracting numbers separately from string column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `stat` that is VARCHAR type and would like to grab all the numbers within it individually. For example, if a specific record in the column has the value `12 to 24 MONTHS Fl` then I would like to grab 12 and 24 separately. I've seen other posts where the numbers end up grouped together and would be `1224` in this case, but how could I do the aforementioned separating of the numbers? Given that I do not know the number of digits in each of the numbers, I was wondering how best to do this. Thanks

For an example like `12 to 24 months APY1.8semi` the output would need to be `12`,`24` and `1.8`, but to be clear there are only whole numbers and there aren't any `.` characters in the column.

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: Also, what is the desired outcome for a value such as `12 to 24 months APY1.8semi`.

Comment: @DannySlor Answered, its a Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @Isolated It would be `12`,`24`,`1.8`.

Comment: If there aren’t any negative numbers `select *
from (values('12 to 24 months APY1.8semi .')) as t(col)
cross apply (values(replace(translate(t.col, '234567890.', '1111111111'), '1', ''))) as c(c)
cross apply (
select s.value
from string_split(translate(t.col, c.c, replicate('a', len(c.c+'.')-1)), 'a') as s
where s.value not in ('', '.')
) as n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shamelessly copied this answer from another post but made a small modification to preserve your spaces. This one is essentially replacing letters with the @ symbol, then replacing the @ symbol.

```
select id, REPLACE(TRANSLATE([comments], 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+()- ,#+', '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'), '@', ' ')
from my_data
```

| id | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 24 |
| 2 | 12 24 1.8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uAWdKTCE)

Or if you would prefer results as a tall table, then you could apply the `string_split` function.

```
select id, value from (
  select id, ca.value
  from my_data
  cross apply string_split (REPLACE(TRANSLATE([comments], 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+()- ,#+', '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'), '@', ','), ',')ca
  )z
where value <> ''
```

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 24 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 24 |
| 2 | 1.8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7MTf-Srk)

Answer (score 0):

First we create this function.

```
   create function [dbo].[GetNumbersFromText](@String varchar(2000))
    returns table as return
    (
      with C as
      (
        select cast(substring(S.Value, S1.Pos, S2.L) as decimal(10,2)) as Number,
               stuff(s.Value, 1, S1.Pos + S2.L, '') as Value
        from (select @String+' ') as S(Value)
          cross apply (select patindex('%[0-9.]%', S.Value)) as S1(Pos)
          cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9.]%', stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos, ''))) as S2(L)
        union all
        select cast(substring(S.Value, S1.Pos, S2.L) as decimal(10,2)),
               stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos + S2.L, '')
        from C as S
          cross apply (select patindex('%[0-9.]%', S.Value)) as S1(Pos)
          cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9.]%', stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos, ''))) as S2(L)
        where patindex('%[0-9.]%', S.Value) > 0
      )
      select number
      from C
    )
```

Then we use it in our query.

```
select string_agg(number, ', ') as result from GetNumbersFromText('12 to 24 months APY1.8semi')
```

| result |
| --- |
| 12.00, 24.00, 1.80 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zi1GCil8)